# css,sass gradient color as the base color for extjs theming

Tags: css, sass, extjs4.1

I am implementing an extjs theme based on the tutorial:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/theming

I have set everything up and works as expected.

But I want to have a gradient color as the base-color:

I tried the following syntax for sass , but it didnt work.

Any one has suggestions please?

```
 $base-color: gradient(#09B3F0, #0A284A);
```

Comment: "it didnt work", how didn't it work?  Do you have a function in Sass called `gradient`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) and use this mixin:

```
@include background(linear-gradient(#09B3F0, #0A284A));
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CAEgu)

`gradient()` is not a native Sass function, and there is no built in support for gradients. One of the reasons Compass is great is that it makes [CSS3 gradients](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/images/)—and other features–painless to use.